# Do I need to create a copy of the database file multiple times? or just once in the appdelegate?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

What do I need to set up the database in my ios project? I know I have to make a copy of the database file but do I need to rewrite the same setup code in each view controller where I plan to actually retrieve and save data?

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameDefault.sqlite"];

[self createAndCheckDatabase];
```

I have this in my appdelegate, but do I need to have the same code in my facebook view controller where I plan to save user info?

Comment: Are you to using core data to access the sqlite file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a single instance of [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), initialised with the path, across your app and view controllers. FMDB will create the DB for you if it doesn't exist.